# Query database in Joomla 2.5

Tags: php, joomla

I'm using Joomla 2.5 and I need to retrieve the field 'avatar' for the current user.

This is the code I'm using:

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
$id = $user->get('id');

$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$query->select('avatar')
 ->from('#__discuss_users')
 ->where('id = $id');

$db->setQuery($query);
$results = $db->loadObjectList();
```

But it isn't displaying any data. I tried changing the last line to:

```
$results = $db->loadResult();
```

But it doesn't work either.

Comment: did you try `echo $query` and run manually in MySQL?

Comment: echo $query returns: SELECT avatar FROM #__discuss_users WHERE id = $id

Comment: Is there any `$id` value? Please check it and keep it in this query.. And then run this query.. may be you have blank row..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your help. The following code works:

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
$id = $user->get('id');

$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$query
 ->select($db->quoteName('avatar'))
 ->from($db->quoteName('#__discuss_users'))
 ->where('id = '.$id);

$db->setQuery($query);
$results = $db->loadResult();
echo $results;
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using it as you posted, you won't include the actual value of $id in your query. You need to append it to the string like this:

```
$query->select('avatar')
 ->from('#__discuss_users')
 ->where('id = '.$id);
```

I am usually not using the $query->select stuff, but a plain old query. Thus, you might try to do it like this (this might not be best practice though):

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
$id = $user->get('id');

$db = JFactory::getDBO();  
// $query = $db->getQuery(true);

$query = "SELECT ".$db->quoteName('avatar')
         ." FROM ".$db->quoteName('#__discuss_users')
         ." WHERE ".$db->quoteName('id')
         ." = ".$db->quote($id).";";

// $query->select('avatar')
// ->from('#__discuss_users')
// ->where('id = $id');

$db->setQuery($query);
$results = $db->loadObjectList();
```

Comment: That's right. I made the correction, but I just don't get any results. echo $query is returning the right SQL command, since I tested in the command line.

Comment: See my edit, I can't put the right formatting in this comment. And note that I am always using getDBO (caps) - don't know if this makes a difference.

Comment: Yep, the $db->quoteName() hit me in the beginning, too... :-) glad it is working now.